# Why downvotes status is not showing in question page?

Tags: support, down-votes

Actually I am stuck with a downvote found in my question page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android).

In my profile page its shows me down vote in question as well as answer also.

> [image]

But when I check same thing in that question page then I am not able to see any sign of that downvote.

Here, it shows `-10 & -5` but is it really lost or something else?

**Question Link**

> [image]

**Answer Link**

> [image]

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with that? Is it a bug or have I really lost some points?

I don't know is it bug or what is that. So please share your idea.

Comment: Those aren't downvotes. Those are unupvotes.

Comment: yeah, but if we get any down vote they sowing dove sign in page, but they are not showing right now

Comment: @Mysticial, hey check out what I posted in chat about my unupvote question from earlier today, http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1719667#1719667

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event on your reputation page doesn't show any downvotes. It is "**unupvote**". That means a user upvoted your post then unupvoted it. So you lose 5 reputation from your question and 10 from your answer.

> [image: unupvote]

Comment: okay, it mean user has change his mind and remove his up vote. so that will not count as up vote as well as down vote. is it like that

Comment: Yes. It is just an undo of the upvote. If the unvoting happens on the same day, it will just remove the upvote event like it never happened before.

Comment: okay.okay thanks. Now its clear for me :) Tq

Comment: @Antony - Seriously I was about to post the same image with almost same free hand circle as your. :)